# Optional`s Equatable in Swift

Tags: swift, option-type

We can compare two Optional variables through

```
public func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool
```

But when i compare a `String?` and a `String`, it goes into the same function above. Why not:

```
public func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T) -> Bool
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In general, a function with arguments of some optional Type (`Type?`) does not imply the necessity of a variable of optional type as an input. In other words, take some function `foo` such that

```
func foo(in: Type?) { ... }
```

What this really means is that the function accepts both `nil` and `Type` variables as inputs (when unwrapped). Logically this is `nil || Type`, so of course a variable of class `Type?` can be taken as an input because it is identically `nil` or `Type` when unwrapped. However, even further, `Type` (non-optional) works just fine too because it satisfies one of the conditions in the logical expression.

Comment: @季亨达 Feel free to upvote and mark the answer as correct. Glad to help.